# Is an iOS In-App Purchase transaction ID always a long integer?

Tags: ios, database, in-app-purchase, schema

I'm creating a game where I'm saving the in-app purchase history in a database. I'm designing the database and I need to know if the `transaction_id` returned from the receipt verification from Apple servers is always a number that fits in 64-bits. It seems so, but I just need to be sure. Did anyone see anything else? If it is always a long integer, I'll design my database as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of a thumb when dealing with integer values in databases:

> If you do not plan on performing any types of mathematical
>   calculations on the field, store it as a string.

Also [according to docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionIdentifier), it is a string:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *transactionIdentifier
```

Comment: I'm not a database master, but how would that affect indexing performance?

Comment: I assume it will be a bit slower, but that shouldn't matter.